# Change certain values of a vector based on mean and standard deviation of its subsets

Tags: r, anomaly-detection

I am trying to inject anomalies into a dataset, essentially changing certain values, based on a condition. I have a dataset, there are 10 subsets. The condition is that anomalies would be 2.8-3 times the standard deviation of each segment away from the mean of that subset. For that, I am dividing the dataset into 10 equal parts, then calculating the mean and standard deviation of each subset, and changing certain values by putting them 3 standard deviations of that subset away from the mean of that subset. The code looks like the following:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- rnorm(sample(1:35000, 32000, replace=F),0,1) #create dataset
y <- cumsum(x) #cumulative sum of dataset
j=1
for(i in c(1:10)){ 
  seg = y[j:j+3000] #name each subset seg 
  m = mean(seg)     #mean of subset
  print(m)

  s = sd(seg)       # standard deviation of subset
  print(s)

  o_data = sample(j:j+3000,10) #draw random numbers from j to j + 3000
  print(o_data)

 y[o_data] = m + runif(10, min=2.8, max=3) * s #values = mean + 2.8-3 * sd
 print(y[o_data])

 j = j + 3000 # increment j
 print(j)
```

}

The error I get is that standard deviation is NA, so I am not able to set the values.

What other approach is there by which I can accomplish the task? I have the inject anomalies which are 2.8-3 standard deviations away from the rolling mean essentially.

Comment: Segment, subset: same or different? Once you perturb your dataset, typically mean and SD themselves change.

Comment: Yes i used segment and subset interchangably.

Comment: Fine, but clean up the question to one term, not two.

Comment: done, changed segments to subset

Answer (score 1):

You have a simple error in your code. when you wrote
`seg = y[j:j+3000]` I believe that you meant  `seg = y[j:(j+3000)]`
Similarly `o_data = sample(j:j+3000,10)` should be `o_data = sample(j:(j+3000),10)`